# Creating Outlook appointment using ICal

Tags: c#, outlook

I have written some code in c# that creates an ical file and attaches the file to an Outlook email.  Is there a way to create an appointment that appears directly in Outlook calendar as accepted instead of a user having to open the attachment and accept it?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about sending an appointment to someone else and getting it added to their calendar, I'm pretty sure that's not possible.  At least, I **hope** that's not possible.

If you're talking about adding an appointment to your own calendar, you can use the Outlook automation objects for this.  Add a reference to the Microsoft Outlook Object Library, and then do something like this:

```
using System;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Outlook.Application ol= new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.AppointmentItem cal = ol.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
            cal.Start = DateTime.Now;
            cal.End = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
            cal.Subject = "Test";
            cal.Save();
        }
    }
}
```